An Earth with only heart-shaped clouds
So I have another Earth-like planet that can only form heart-shaped clouds like this: 
It is a result of natural forces.
What would the planet need to achieve this?

Clouds change shape all the time. Literally as you look at them they change shape. To understand why, fill a glass with water and drop a drop of ink. Fluid dynamics is computationally hard.

To add to @AlexP's comment... the shape of a heart is only true from the perspective of someone who can see that shape. Someone else twenty miles away would likely see something completely different. BTW, and fair warning... science really can't solve all problems. It's unfair to use the word "silly," but the sillier your idea, the less likely science can rationalize it - and that fairly quickly.

It is like an angel.

When tasked with the scientifically impossible, start with the assumption it is true, and build new scientific principles to fit.
The good thing about science is that no one really cares how much science "makes since" as long as it is consistent and repeatable.  Take Quantum Superposition: it literally defies logic, and the more you study it, the more you understand it, the more your realize it's a thing that simply makes no actual sense from the perspective of any kind of directly observable physics... but we like to pretend that it does because we made up some rules and functions to describe it.
Within our own rules of science, there is no way for heart shaped clouds to be the norm, because within our rules of science, they are not heart-shaped. The math and the models and the explanations are all secondary to the observation. So, instead of trying to say something is impossible by our own rules, it simply must be true, and the science will adapt.
In our world, the shape of clouds can be described by the Navier-Stokes Equations which are so complex that... well lets just say they aren't really worth explaining outside of the context of high fidelity fluid dynamics simulations.  But luckily for you, water vapor in your universe is even more complex than this!  Due to the unique ionic bonding patterns of water vapor in your world it accumulates in a hypercardioid pattern that naturally orients with the direction of gravity. This unique property of water vapor causes it to settle into heart shapes because it achieves a special phase of matter that allows it to act like both a crystal and a gas at the same time.  After all, in our own world, we already have superfluids, supercritical fluids, and multiple solid phases for the same molecule (Ice-I, Ice-II, etc.) so who's to notice or care that one other odd phase of matter exists.
Just say that it for some reason follows a Hypercardioid function that looks something like this:

αΔ = (αx^2 + (9/4)(αy^2) + αz^2 -1)^3 - (αx^2)(αz^3) -(9/200)(αy^2)(αz^3)

Scientists will all nod their heads and agree that this function does indeed describe the shape of those heart shaped clouds, so whatever explanation you use to explain it will sound about right.

Elementary School students will all learn that clouds are heart-shaped because that is what they are.
High School students will all learn that they look this way because of something called the Cornimbus Effect... but no high school teacher will know how to describe it; so, they just namedrop the principle right between Rayleigh Scattering and Electromagnetism which they can equally only explain in the most simple of terms.
Undergraduates learn the equations, but understand it even less.
Graduates start to apply the equations on a regular basis and think they understand it.
Postgraduates realize it really makes no sense, but that is okay because clouds are heart-shaped because that is what they are.


After the Flood, God has promised Noah to not exterminate the Humanity again, not even if we would fully deserve that. As a symbol of this promise, He made the clouds hearth-shaped.

12 And God said, “This is the sign of the covenant I am making between me and you and every living creature with you, a covenant for all generations to come: 13 I have set my hearth in the clouds, and it will be the sign of the covenant between me and the earth. 14 Whenever I bring clouds over the earth and the hearth appears in the clouds, 15 I will remember my covenant between me and you and all living creatures of every kind. Never again will the waters become a flood to destroy all life. 16 Whenever the hearth appears in the clouds, I will see it and remember the everlasting covenant between God and all living creatures of every kind on the earth.”

That is an altered Bible, as you are from an altered reality. The real version can be read here.

Not a "science-based" answer, but I personally like it because it represents a natural step in how people like to describe things.  First we see the thing.  Then we tell stories to explain it.  Then we tell more and more "scientific" sounding stories about it until someone tells a story that is indistinguishable from a "science".  If your society does not have the science to explain a thing in detail, then the origin tale will likely be the dominate explanation until a better one exists.

many reputable scientists to this day continue to believe in supernatural explanations to things that science can not at this time do a better job of explaining.

@Nosajimiki Originally it was not tagged as science-based :-) You know, essence of the science is that the laws of the Universe are eternal, always and everywhere the same. At most we don't know them enough well. We are things in it, and our soul is actually protein structures, governed by the same eternal laws. Essence of solipsism, including buddhism, is that the Universe is the product of our imagination, essentially it is a big dream. We are dreaming it. What if reality is halfway between the two.

@Nosajimiki For example, what if a millenia ago, the Earth was yet really flat, only because we did not know the laws of the Physics enough well? You might say, we have tremendous amount of proof that it was always spherical. And that is right - but we have these proofs only now, and not then.

@Nosajimiki Science is unique in the sense that it can show that it has limits. It is a relative new development, it is not yet a century old, but it exists: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeQX2HjkcNo Before that, the widely shared scientific consent was that we will know soon the answer for all questions and the history will end. "Wonderful" political systems were born on this idea. Most atheists still believe this idea, most of them are just late.

It's actually swarms of microbes.
This might be pushing the boundaries of science-based worldbuilding, but I think it's plausible. In the real world, water vapour droplets in clouds tend to form around some kind of nucleus - often dust or a microbe. Maybe there is a species of airborne microbe in your world which happens to fill the air in enormous heart-shaped colonies. Think of coral - thousands of microscopic creatures form colonies in intricate shapes. Perhaps the heart shape is related to the way the colony reproduces, or the way it remains in the air.
Yes, I know that this proposal isn't totally airtight, but it contains much less handwaving and magic than any other answer I can think of!

There is no real way for cloud formation to only naturally occur as a heart shape. Clouds are formed when water vapour settles on some particles like dust. https://climatekids.nasa.gov/cloud-formation
So you would need a heart shape pattern of particles, which stay evenly distributed for water vapour to form and no other particles flying off individually on their own. That really can't happen naturally other then maybe some volcano with a heart shaped crater being the only source of particles on the surface of a planet (other than water), and somehow these particles structured together so they don't clump and also don't seperate, could be some weird magnetic properties of the particles.
Even then though you may get some heart shaped clouds, but then heart shaped clouds could hit other heart shaped clouds and then no longer be heart shaped, so this is pretty impossible.
Now for not naturally occurring then you can have some lighther than air contraption for water vapour to settle on, and somehow for it to repel against other contraptions, but also still no other particles for water vapour to form on. No sand, no dust, no flakes of metal, rock, soil or any other matter than water and your contraptions.
Impossible for naturally occurring (because no planet where clouds could form would exist like this), and practically impossible for non naturally occuring.

Didn't you know...?
It is obvious that heart-shaped clouds are a necessary consequence of the unicorns on antarctica which rub their horns on one another which then causes electrostatic discharges to influence water vapor in the atmosphere to strongly adapt to the 120-degree H2O atom spacing configuration which happens to look like a heart (some will say it just looks like a wide "v" - but those are not to be taken seriously). Because of atmospheric wind conditions the heart shape is not assumed with sharply defined edges. At the edges, winds are able to distort or split the atom bonds which results in the irregular outer shapes. If you zoom in closely you will find that each of the cloud fragments is itself shaped like a heart. This is why heart-shaped clouds can appear in any sizes. In fact any dipol configuration of any gas would form heart-shaped clouds in the sky.
In case you do not believe that unicorns exist (how dare you!) you also can consider Coriolis forces, existing because of the earth's rotation on a (skewed) axis, are the reason for increased electrostatic interactions on water vapor in the atmosphere.
Also, because of increased pollution particles in the atmosphere (climate change FTW yay), sunlight gets more scattered  but because of the longer wavelength red light is largely unaffected, resulting in the clouds to appear shifted to the red side of the light spectrum in color. The correct scientific designation is "cumulus cordialis pinkus" - in common tongue "pink heart clouds".
The provided picture is thus either a historical photography or photoshoped or altered by AI tools (pick two). The blue hue is far to intense, there should be a much higher red hue to it to be taken as a genuine picture.
